# Alternatives to Distill Web Monitor

Tags: rss

I'm looking for an alternative to the [Distill Web Monitor](https://distill.io/apps/web-monitor). I use it to watch web pages (via specific [Div elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)) which don't supply an RSS or Atom feed, and therefore can't add to [Feedly.com](http://feedly.com/). For my usage I can't justify the prices Distill are trying to charge, and want an alternative - preferably open source.

I would prefer a desktop application for Windows, or a web app. I'm a developer by day so open source projects suggestion are also welcome (i.e. something I can contribute to or at least compile).